# Display total values in javascript quotation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I am trying to learn and understand js/jquery operation, and today I am loosing my mind on a simple function issue.

I would like to create a kind of quotation form that displays below the form an auto-updated calculated price depending on the checked/unchecked boxes, radio buttons and number input in the form.

Here is a *little bit* working example :

[CSSdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/0fov8vdl)

In this example, I can display my Items total price (number of items * itemprice var), and my total price (checkboxes and radio buttons total value) separately. I would like that my Total Price include Items total price on each event :

- `$("input:checkbox, input:radio").click`
- `$('#nbItems').change`

My other question is that my + and - buttons on each side of my input interacts with its content, but not with the Item total price, despite many unsuccessful attempts :(

Here is another attempt by editing my calcTotal() function, but I am obviously understanding/doing something wrong... :

[CSSdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xnvpzkqn)

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post relevant code here since broken links are not useful to people coming after. There is a snippet editor at SO too. Click the little picture frame when editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery `trigger()` function after changing the values using your buttons

Change to this snippet of code:

```
$('#cnt-up').click(function() {
    itemsAmount.val(Math.min(parseInt($('#nbItems').val()) + 1, 20));
    $("#nbItems").trigger("change"); // add this line
});
$('#cnt-down').click(function() {
    itemsAmount.val(Math.max(parseInt($('#nbItems').val()) - 1, 0));
    $("#nbItems").trigger("change"); // add this line
});
```

This fires the `change` event which is handled later on in your code

In the other part of your question, to keep the total updated, change the `calcTotal()` function to:

```
function calcTotal(){

total = 0; // reset

    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        //This happens for each checked input field
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        total += parseInt(value); 

    });

total += $("#nbItems").val() * itemPrice;
}
```

and call it from the `$("#nbItems").change()` event:

```
$('#nbItems').change(function(){
    $('#result').text($(this).val() * itemPrice);
    calcTotal();
    $('#total').text(total);
});
```